# Error compiling GhostPDL for PASE (AIX) on OS/400 V5R4

Tags: ibm-midrange, gcc

I'm trying to compile ghostpdl 9.07 on V5R4 in QP2TERM (the AIX-like PASE environment).

After downloading and untarring the package to /QOpenSys, I ran:

```
CALL QP2TERM
```

and then in QP2TERM:

```
./configure --build="powerpc-ibmaix5.3.0.0"
gmake
```

This ended with the error:

```
In file included from ../gs/base/gp_psync.c:20:                
/usr/include/pthread.h:582: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:585: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:589: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:592: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:595: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:598: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:601: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:604: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:607: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:611: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:614: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:625: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:629: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:652: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:655: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:658: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:661: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:664: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:672: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:675: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:678: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:681: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:689: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:693: error: parse error before '*' token
/usr/include/pthread.h:696: error: parse error before '*' token
gmake[2]: *** [obj/gp_psync.o] Error 1                         
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/QOpenSys/ghostpdl-9.07/main'     
gmake[1]: *** [pdl-product] Error 2                            
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/QOpenSys/ghostpdl-9.07/main'     
gmake: *** [pcl] Error 2
```

Some googling made me believe that installing pth-1.4.0-2.aix4.3.ppc.rpm and pth-devel-1.4.0-2.aix4.3.ppc.rpm would help rectify things, but gmake yielded the same error afterward.

Other forums suggested an old version of gcc was the culprit (3.x) but running:

```
gcc -v
```

yields:

```
Using built-in specs.                                                        
Target: powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0                                               
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --d
isable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/opt/freeware --enable-threads -
-enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --host=powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0          
Thread model: aix                                                            
gcc version 4.0.0
```

Comment: How did you install the gcc toolchain?  Have you seen [How to Compile Ghostscript for PASE](http://hewhocutsdown.net/blog/2012/04/25/how-to-compile-ghostscript-for-pase/)?

Comment: I wrote that. :)

Same methodology for installing gcc as outlined on that blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is m_setjmp.h (make will throw '_UKJBLEN' undeclared here (not in a function) error) you'll need to get AIX to TL5 (tech level 5). To my knowledge this is not possible in PASE on V5R4, you'll need to get an AIX machine that's at TL5 to compile; you can then use the compiled executable in PASE.